# Integral $ \int_0^{\pi/2} x \sqrt{\cot x} \, dx $

Tags: integration

I cannot evaluate the following integral

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} x \sqrt{\cot x} \, dx $$

which means

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\tan x}} \, dx = 0.97482\ldots. $$

This integral seems to be equal to the value of

$$ \frac\pi{2\sqrt2} \left( \frac\pi2 - \ln2 \right) = 0.97482\ldots. $$

If anyone knows how to solve this integral, I would be very interested to know. (Or do you know what would be a generalization of this integral? And do you know how to prove it?)

*P.S.* This intgral is equal to

$$ \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{\frac1x} \tan^{-1} x + \sqrt{x} \tan^{-1} \frac1x}{1+x^2} \, dx. $$

Comment: Mathematica returns a very long and nasty antiderivative. The problem is to evaluate at the bounds. Numerically, the numbers match at least for $1,000$ figures

Comment: How did you come up with the closed-form value?

Comment: Mathematica tells the solution:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} x \sqrt{\cot (x)} \, dx=\frac{1}{4} G_{3,3}^{2,3}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{4} \\
 -\frac{1}{4},0,-\frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)\simeq 0.97482...$$

with G the MeijerG function.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511773/evaluating-int-0-pi-x-frac-sin-fracx2-cos-fracx2-sqrt-sin/4511829#4511829   or, more general case, here -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881409/evaluation-of-the-definite-integral-int-0-pi-2x-tanxpdx?noredirect=1

Answer (score 8):

Your integral is equivalent to
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan t}{\sqrt{t} \,(1+t^2)} \, dt $$
by substituting $x=\arctan t$. To evaluate this, we recall a well known integral from complex analysis:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{1+t} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}, \hspace{0.5cm} 0<\text{re}(s)<1 $$

Substituting $x^2t^2$ for $t$, where $x$ is some positive real number, and replacing $s$ with $\frac{s}{2}$ gives
$$ \frac{\pi x^{-s}}{2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{1+(xt)^2} \, dt, \hspace{0.5cm} 0<s<2, \; x>0 $$
Subtracting two such expressions gives
$$ \frac{\pi (1-x^{2-s})}{2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})} = \int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1} \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2} - \frac{x^2}{1+(xt)^2} \right) dt = (1-x^2) \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{(1+t^2)(1+(xt)^2)} \, dt $$
and therefore
$$ \frac{\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})} \frac{1-x^{2-s}}{1-x^2} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{(1+t^2)(1+(xt)^2)} \, dt, \hspace{0.5cm} 0<s<2, \; x>0 $$
We now integrate both sides with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$ and apply Fubini's theorem on the right, which is justified by absolute convergence. This gives
$$ \frac{\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})} \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2-s}}{1-x^2} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{1+t^2} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+(xt)^2} \, dt = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-2} \arctan t}{1+t^2} \, dt $$
Finally setting $s=\frac{3}{2}$ we obtain the integral you're looking for on the right and
$$ \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{1-t}{1-t^4} \, 2tdt = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{2t}{(1+t)(1+t^2)} \, dt \\ = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t} \right) dt $$
on the left. Can you finish things off?

Comment: Superb answer !

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $t=\sqrt{\cot x}$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2} x \sqrt{\cot x} \, dx \\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{2t^2\cot^{-1}t^2}{1+t^4}dt
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{2t^4}{(1+t^4)(y^2+t^4)}dy\ dt\\
=& \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac2{1-y^2}\left(\frac1{1+t^4}-\frac{y^2}{y^2+t^4}\right)dt\ dy\\
=&\ \frac\pi{\sqrt2}\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt y}{1-y^2}dy
=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}(\pi -2\ln2)
\end{align}